# C# ADO.Net transaction in for loop not inserting all records and insert only one record

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have the following code. Only the first record is getting inserted and no more records added.
Is there any issue with my code?

```
foreach (var learningAimFund in learningDelivery.LearningDeliveryFAM)
{
    var fundingMonitoringType = learningAimFund.LearnDelFAMType;
    var fieldId = FundingMonitoringUtil.GetFundingMonitoringFieldId(fundingMonitoringType);
    await _databaseAccess.ExecuteScalarAsync(
        LearningAimFundingDataStoredProcedures.INSERT, 
        new List<Parameter>
        {
            new Parameter(nameof(LearningAimFundingData.LearnerId), newLearnerId),
            new Parameter(nameof(LearningAimFundingData.LearningAimFundingId), aimFundingId),
            new Parameter(nameof(LearningAimFundingData.FieldId), fieldId),
            new Parameter(nameof(LearningAimFundingData.Data), learningAimFund.LearnDelFAMCode)
        }, 
        transaction);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Wrap that ExecureScaler in a Try Catch.

Comment: Are you sure thats pure ADO.NET? I don't see any Microsoft documentation for any `ExecuteScalarAsync` methods that take in parameters like that.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalarasync?view=net-5.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalarasync)

Comment: What’s the type of _databaseAccess. have used any package from nuget? If it is your own library do post how executescalarasync is implemented.

Comment: @TimothyG., it seems this is .NET Core using [Microsoft.Datta.SqlClient[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalarasync).

Comment: Do you have a primary Key?  When you have a primary key only one row will exist in the database for each key.  So if you have a primary key and the key is the same for all entries than you will get only one row in the database.